# Not able to download latest version of Chrome driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
i am not able download the latest version of Chrome driver i.e. ChromeDriver 2.33
any one facing the same issue ?
I am getting below error message
"This site can’t be reached"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine for me.

It could be your network that is limiting access.  Try checking your network settings (or changing networks) or speak to your admin if the problem continues.